# ¿Significa algo "vilo" por sí solo? ¿Cuál es su etimología?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, locuciones

En el diccionario encontramos la siguiente expresión:

> **[en vilo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bpfd3xx)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. Sin el apoyo físico necesario o sin estabilidad.
>
> 2. loc. adv. Con indecisión, inquietud y zozobra.

Es decir, la palabra "vilo" se usa siempre con la preposición "en" delante, y eso lo recogen así hasta los diccionarios más antiguos, que no dicen nada acerca de dónde viene la palabra.

Así pues, ¿significa "vilo" algo por sí solo? ¿Cuál es su etimología?

Comment: Sí, "vilo" por sí solo significa que lo he visto  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**vilo** no significa nada por sí solo, solo se usa en la expresion *en vilo*.

Según Corominas, su forma se debe a la influencia de la otra expresión *en vago* ("sin firmeza ni consistencia"), que también se ve reflejada en *en vano* ("inútilmente").

Según esta fuente, *en vilo* deriva de **vil**, palabra derivada del latín *vilis* ("barato, sin valor"). Originalmente habría significado "sin firmeza, sin estabilidad", como en la frase *paredes en vilo*, es decir, paredes que están a punto de caer. Luego derivó a su actual significado de "levantado en el aire".

De *vil* también derivan *vileza, vilipendiar*, y *envilecer*

Comment: Interesante propuesta. He leído por algún sitio (creo que fue en Etimologías de Chile) que tiene la misma raíz que "filo" o "hilo": "filum". Así, estar "en vilo" sería lo mismo que decir "estar en el filo" (al borde). ¿Qué opinas de ese posible origen?

Comment: Leí la referencia que indicas en [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?vilo) y me parece que es una alternativa posible, a pesar de que ahí no se indica alguna fuente confiable que la respalde. Sin embargo, me cabe la duda de que efectivamente haya habido una evolución de /f/ a /v/, ya que esto no es algo que haya ocurrido habitualmente en la historia del español (aunque sí ocurrió en la evolución de otros idiomas).

Answer (score 1):

La palabra "vilo" al igual que "filo" e "hilo", provienen, de filum, palabra latina para designar bordes finísimos.  Lo cual haría que tuviera sentido la expresion "esta en vilo".

Comment: No está claro que *vilo* comparta la misma etimología. En todo caso, citá fuentes

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/25688)