# Palabras que solo se usan en locuciones

Tags: vocabulario

Algunas palabras se usan casi exclusivamente en locuciones. Estoy pensando en **ínfulas,** que aparece casi siempre en la forma **tener ínfulas** (solo la he encontrado de otro modo en los textos en los que se explica el origen de esta expresión y siempre en plural). ¿Alguna otra?

Answer (score 4):

La palabra [**vilo**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bpfd3xx) solo se usa en la expresión **en vilo**. Puedes verlo en [¿Significa algo “vilo” por sí solo? ¿Cuál es su etimología?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22985/6915).

Answer (score 2):

Hay multitud de casos en el diccionario, y algunos se han tratado en este sitio anteriormente. Yo acabo de encontrar uno gracias a una [respuesta de walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28148/12637) a otra pregunta: [*ripiao*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WVQuMKY) solo se usa en la expresión *perico ripiao*. También puedes consultar la pregunta [What's "bríos" in the Spanish expression "voto a bríos"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22786/12637).